# Js search issues with regexp. Email check

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok now I try to check if input email is valid with this regexp:

```
$("#lastNameSend").val().search(/.*@.*\..*/)
```

This never returns anything. Why?
here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jupnzty0/13/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

First your fiddle function is not having opening curly brackets--

```
$(document).on("click","#sendPhysButton", function(event)

    alert($("#lastNameSend").val().search(/.*@.*\..*/));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

It should be

```
$(document).on("click","#sendPhysButton", function(event)
{
    alert($("#lastNameSend").val().search(/.*@.*\..*/));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now it will return -1 if regex is not satisfied.Also, I prefer to use this regex-

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jupnzty0/15/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click","#sendPhysButton", function(event){
    var reg =  /.*@.*\..*/;
    alert(reg.test($("#lastNameSend").val()));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty waterproof email check:

```
/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i
```

If it throws -1, you can implement an error message.